# When to use the select clause in the JPA criteria API?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria, criteria-api

1. Without using `CriteriaQuery#select()` :

   ```
   public List<Address> getAddressOfManager(String designation, String name, String orderByColumn) {

       Boolean ascending = false;
       CriteriaBuilder cb = emanager.getCriteriaBuilder();
       CriteriaQuery<Address> cq = cb.createQuery(Address.class);
       Root<Address> root = cq.from(Address.class);
       //cq.select(root);  <-------------
       Join<Address, Employee> employeeAddress = root.join(Address_.employee);
       Join<Employee,Project> employeeProject = employeeAddress.join(Employee_.project);
       cq.where(cb.or(cb.equal(employeeProject.get(Project_.name), name),cb.equal(employeeAddress.get(Employee_.designation), designation)));
       Order order = ascending ? cb.asc(root.get(orderByColumn))
               : cb.desc(root.get(orderByColumn));
       cq.orderBy(order);
       List<Address> result = emanager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
       return result;
   }
   ```
2. With `CriteriaQuery#select()` :

   ```
   public List<Address> getAddressOfManager(String designation, String name, String orderByColumn) {

       Boolean ascending = false;
       CriteriaBuilder cb = emanager.getCriteriaBuilder();
       CriteriaQuery<Address> cq = cb.createQuery(Address.class);
       Root<Address> root = cq.from(Address.class);
       cq.select(root); //<----------------
       Join<Address, Employee> employeeAddress = root.join(Address_.employee);
       Join<Employee,Project> employeeProject = employeeAddress.join(Employee_.project);
       cq.where(cb.or(cb.equal(employeeProject.get(Project_.name), name),cb.equal(employeeAddress.get(Employee_.designation), designation)));
       Order order = ascending ? cb.asc(root.get(orderByColumn))
               : cb.desc(root.get(orderByColumn));
       cq.orderBy(order);
       List<Address> result = emanager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
       return result;
   }
   ```

   Now, I am confused as to when to use `select()` in JPA criteria query.

Comment: `cq.select(root);` is inferred in JPA criteria that will select all fields in the associated entity(ies) and consequently from the corresponding database table(s). You however, need to be explicit, when you want to select a few of them.

Answer (score 29):

There are basically two ways to specify the *projection term* (or simply saying the *selection term*) on the [`CriteriaQuery<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html) interface in which the query result is to be specified :

```
CriteriaQuery<T> select(Selection<? extends T> selection);
CriteriaQuery<T> multiselect(Selection<?>... selections);
```

Often the projection term used is the candidate class (`Address` in your examples) of the query itself. It may be implicit as in your first example.

The query from the `Address` entity in your first example does not explicitly specify its projection term and it is the same as explicitly selecting the candidate class itself in this case.

A candidate persistent entity itself as the only projection term is implicitly inferred.

---

*When the projected result of the query **is however, something other than the candidate persistent entity itself**, several other constructs are available to shape the result of the query. These constructs are available in the [`CriteriaBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html) interface.*

**Methods to shape query result :**

```
CompoundSelection<Y> construct(Class<Y> result, Selection<?>... terms);
CompoundSelection<Object[]> array(Selection<?>... terms);
CompoundSelection<Tuple> tuple(Selection<?>... terms);
```

<sub>For the sake of completeness only, I will try to demonstrate each of them in turn with a simple example for each of them.</sub>

---

**Shaping query result into instances of a class (a non persistent entity) by `construct()`:**

The [`construct()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#construct(java.lang.Class,%20javax.persistence.criteria.Selection...)) method creates an instance of the given class argument and invokes a constructor (of a non-persistent entity) with values from the input selection terms. These arguments to the constructor of a non-persistent entity (not even an entity, a plain Java class) must match in number, order and type (datatype) with values corresponding to the input selection terms, for example.

```
CriteriaQuery<EmployeeDetails> q = cb.createQuery(EmployeeDetails.class);
Root<Employee> root = q.from(Employee.class);
q.select(cb.construct(EmployeeDetails.class, root.get(Employee_.empName), root.get(Employee_.salary));
```

`EmployeeDetails` in this case, is a plain Java class -- a non-persistent entity that has a constructor which takes two parameters of type `String` (for `empName`) and `BigDecimal` (for `salary`).

The query returns a `List<EmployeeDetails>` -- a non-persistent entity from the selected `Employee`s -- a persistent entity.

<sub>Depending upon the number of rows returned, the query may also return `EmployeeDetails` using the [`getSingleResult()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getSingleResult()) method, for example.</sub>

Multiple selection items can also be combined into a compound selection term that represents an `Object[]` or `Tuple` as shown below.

**Shaping query result into an `Object[]` :**

```
CriteriaQuery<Object[]> q = cb.createQuery(Object[].class);
Root<Employee> root = q.from(Employee.class);
q.select(cb.array(root.get(Employee_.empName), root.get(Employee_.salary));
List<Object[]> list = entityManager.createQuery(q).getResultList();
```

As can be seen, the query returns a `List<Object[]>`. Each element of this list contains a 0-based array of `Object`s - `Object[]`.

**Shaping query result into a [`Tuple`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Tuple.html) :**

```
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> q = cb.createTupleQuery();
Root<Employee> root = q.from(Employee.class);
Selection<String> empName = root.get(Employee_.empName).alias("empName");
q.select(cb.tuple(empName, root.get(Employee_.salary).alias("salary");
List<Tuple> list = entityManager.createQuery(q).getResultList();

String employeeName = list.get(0).get("empName");//Referring to by using its alias (empName)
String employeeSalary = list.get(0).get(1);//Referring to by using its index (salary)

//Iterate over a list of tuples through a foreach loop using alias.

for (Tuple tuple : list) {
    System.out.println(tuple.get("empName") + " : " + tuple.get("salary"));
}
```

The query returns a `List<Tuple>`. The values held by a `Tuple` are accessible by a 0-based integer index, using an alias name of the [`TupleElement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/TupleElement.html) or directly by the `TupleElement`.

<sub>`CriteriaBuilder#createTupleQuery()` is analogous to `CriteriaBuilder#createQuery(Tuple.class)`.</sub>

**Using [`multiselect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html#multiselect(javax.persistence.criteria.Selection...)) to interpret terms based on result type :**

Input terms are automatically interpreted by the `multiselect()` method based on the result type of the `CriteriaQuery` to automatically arrive at the shape of the result -- the return type of the `CriteriaQuery` in question. For example, the very first example in this answer could be rewritten using `multiselect()` as follows.

```
CriteriaQuery<EmployeeDetails> q = cb.createQuery(EmployeeDetails.class);
Root<Employee> root = q.from(Employee.class);
q.multiselect(root.get(Employee_.empName), root.get(Employee_.salary));
```

Since the type of the result is `EmployeeDetails`, the `multiselect()` method interprets its argument projection terms as constructor arguments of `EmployeeDetails`.

Notice that a construct like this, `cb.construct(EmployeeDetails.class, root.get(Employee_.empName), root.get(Employee_.salary)` as used in the first example, does not have to be used in the preceding example using `multiselect()` which automatically interprets its argument projection terms based on the return type of the query and invokes an appropriate constructor in the result class - `EmployeeDetails`.

If the query were to be specified to return a `Tuple` (or a list of `Tuple`s), the `multiselect()` method with the exact same arguments would create `Tuple` instances instead as shown below.

```
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> q = cb.createTupleQuery();
Root<Employee> root = q.from(Employee.class);
q.multiselect(root.get(Employee_.empName), root.get(Employee_.salary));
```

Needless to mention but the same thing can also be rewritten to return an `Object[]` (or a list of `Object[]`s).

```
CriteriaQuery<Object[]> q = cb.createQuery(Object[].class);
Root<Employee> root = q.from(Employee.class);
q.multiselect(root.get(Employee_.empName), root.get(Employee_.salary));
```

In both the cases, the `muliselect()` method automatically interprets its argument projection terms based on the return type of the query as said earlier which is `Tuple` and `Object[]` respectively.

<sub>It should also be noted that EcliseLink has a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=340089) which is still to be fixed while fetching a single `Boolean` selection term in this way using `multiselect()` as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23651200)</sub>.

---

Depending upon different JPA providers, the behaviour of the `multiselect()` method gets more interesting with `Object` as a result type,

- If the `multiselect()` method is used with a single selection term, the return type is the selected term itself.
- If the `multiselect()` method however, contains more than one input term/selection term/projection term, the result type is `Object[]`.

I am not quite sure about different providers but the selection terms as specified by the `multiselect()` method may not be an array or a collection (or a tuple-valued compound term). The only compound terms which may be allowed as `multiselect()` arguments are those which are created by the `construct()` method which essentially represents a single element in turn.

---

In addition to the above constructs, the usage of [`CriteriaQuery#select(Selection<? extends T> selection)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html#select(javax.persistence.criteria.Selection)) is quite common while using scalar / group / aggregate / single-valued functions such as `count()`, `max()`, `min()` etc and sub-queries. The usage of sub-queries is excluded from this answer for brevity.

> A `Selection` defines what is selected by a query. A Selection can be
>   any object expression, attribute expression, function, sub-select,
>   constructor or aggregation function. An alias can be defined for a
>   `Selection` using the alias() API.
>
> ```
> CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
>
> // Count the total employees
> CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery();
> Root employee = criteriaQuery.from(Employee.class);
> criteriaQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.count(employee)); //<------
> Query query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
> Long result = query.getSingleResult();
>
> // Maximum salary
> CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery();
> Root employee = criteriaQuery.from(Employee.class);
> criteriaQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.max(employee.get("salary")); //<------
> Query query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
> Long result = query.getSingleResult();
> ```

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Criteria#Selection

Comment: Thanks Tiny, But I am still not very clear about it. Any URL for reference can help a lot.

Comment: [JBoss Reference](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html), [Oracle Tutorials - Java EE 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-criteria.htm), [JPA WikiBook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Criteria).

Comment: Are you finding some difficulties in understanding the code snippets or long textual information? It is a single, simple and cut down example being repeated several times. I answered based on a blog which I remember. I intended to quote many things from that blog but unfortunately, I cannot locate that link right now. By the way, the concrete question is answered by a single statement, "*A candidate persistent entity itself as the only projection term is implicitly inferred.*"

Comment: Hello Tiny, Thank you so much .your answer was so descriptive that was helpful to me a lot to understand JPA criteria. especially about projections.

Comment: I know this is late but how can you pass a List of root.get("") in a criteriaQuery.multiselect?